# range validator not functioning

Tags: asp.net, rangevalidator

i have a simple code composed of add edit delete. I have a name,description and price value fields. i want to have a range on the price value ranging from 1 - 10.
though i have this on my code:

```
<td class="style7">
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="1-10" MaximumValue="10" 
                MinimumValue="1"></asp:RangeValidator>
        </td>
```

when i try to click on add, although its within the range of 1-10, its not adding up. any tricks on this? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely add **Type="Integer"** property (or any other type which fits your needs). What is happening now is that your RangeValidator Type is set to String as a default. The comparison occurs for strings which leads to the value string being required to be between "1" and "10".

See [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_9) from MSDN documentation.

Comment: tried it. still not working. the range is 1-1000. i typed in 500 but the rangvalidator error showed up. it seems like its considering my other textbox?

Comment: Well, obviously that **ControlToValidate** attribute value should correspond to the **ID** attribute value of the control being validated.